# *Observational* Consequences of Energy Nonconservation in GR

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, experimental-physics, energy-conservation, gravitational-waves

What are the experimental or rather observable consequences of the non-conservation (or conservation) of energy in GR? Imagine our instruments were $10^3$ or even $10^6$ more sensitive, better resolution and less noisy. Could we observe,  not necessarily demonstrate explicitly by experiment here on Earth, just observe, that energy *is* or is *not* conserved in GR or in any other varieties of post-Newtonian gravitation?

Answer (score 4):

The cosmological expansion of the universe pretty manifestly non-conserves energy. Particles climb a potential hill, but also accelerate. The universe fills up with more and more cosmological constant energy density.

You could fix this in some sort of "Hubble Bubble" scenario, where the universe is "really" asymptotically flat, and matter only exists in a subset of the whole universe, and the cosmological constant is some artifact of the overall potential energy function of the whole universe but the expansion would eventually have to stop or asymptote off in such a scenario, as eventually the matter will be so diffuse it just looks like it's moving in a Minkowski background.

Comment: What do you mean by "eventually"? Would that be observable somehow *today* or in a few gigayears? And are there any other known observable consequences or only this?

Comment: @hyportnex it would depend on the size of the hubble bubble, but yeah, you'd expect effects to unfold over cosmological time, not "human time"

Comment: but what effects are you expecting?  In GR, energy non-conservation is an effect derived from boundary conditions of the spacetime, and so, you only expect to see energy non-conservation at cosmological scales.

Comment: I do not expect anything, I am completely naïve in this, but say gravitational lensing, etc, is an observation on "galactic" spatial/temporal scales to verify space-time curvature and we can see that from here. Are there such observational effects of said boundary conditions resulting in non-conservation or is that can be had on cosmological scales only on which we can only speculate excepting the expansion of the universe?

Comment: @hyportnex: I'm guessing I"m saying, even now, observationally, you can go and look out at the cosmology, and you went and took a newtonian picture of the universe, you'd see "$dE/dt > 0$ if you went and added all of the contributions from the individual stars and galaxies.  The universe's rate of expansion is accelerating, after all, and this has been directly observed.

Comment: OK, one more question. Your second paragraph on the "Hubble bubble" seems to imply that there could be some *other* explanation. Can there be observational effect against that interpretation?

Comment: @hyportnex: the big problem with a "Hubble Bubble" model is that the deviation from istropy and homogenity happens outside of our hubble horizon, so it's impossible to know about the details of the bubble.  It's just a convenient way to get rid of some of the "bad seeming" features of our cosmology.  But, in principle, it cannot be observationally diferent than standard FRLW cosmology, unless the difference somehow matters for explaining inflation or the big bang singularity.

Comment: summarizing all this, is it fair to say that the *only* observational evidence is and can be the accelerating expansion even including any potential counter argument for that cannot be checked experimentally anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

> Could we observe, not necessarily demonstrate explicitly by experiment here on Earth, just observe, that energy is or is not conserved in GR or in any other varieties of post-Newtonian gravitation?

One simple way to observe nonconservation of energy in gravity is to become an observer in a state of free fall, where atmospheric resistance does not stabilize the speed. Huge celestial objects are accelerating in that frame, some of them gaining lots of kinetic energy from nothing, and some of them losing it to nothing. For example, when falling out of a building or mountain, in the falling person's frame, the most prominent body increasing its kinetic energy by immense amounts is the Earth.

In general relativity, all frames are "equivalent", so we can't dismiss this by "it's just because we're looking at energy in a bad frame" like we would in classical mechanics. If energy conservation works in one frame but not in others, then in GR, it does not work.

Comment: would your argument be also valid for linear or angular momentum (non)conservation and what does this have to do with the problem of boundary conditions Schirmer is referring to?

Comment: I think so. Linear momentum is not conserved in the falling observer frame. Angular momentum nonconservation happens e.g. with angular momentum of the Moon in Earth's frame (the distance between the two increases by cca 4cm/year, while Earth's rotation slows down; if this conserves angular momentum in independent inertial frame, then it probably does not in Earth's frame). It seems that if we want to treat all frames as equivalent, we have to abandon any hope for universal conservation laws.

Comment: Jerry Schirmer's point is about specific well known toy models of cosmos, which manifest energy nonconservation (accelerating expansion...). My point is more about the problem with some frames, which does not depend on any specific model of the universe. Conservation of energy or momentum seems to be a special property of certain class of frames under certain conditions, not to be expected in general.

Comment: Just one more question. Naively I thought that the "energy non-conservation" is a bit more "fundamental", if that is the right word, than just the relativity of all frames in the sense similar to the "steady-state model" in which matter is continuously created. Not saying they are the same just something more like that. Is that the wrong interpretation?

Comment: That meaning of energy nonconservation (production) is indeed different than what I explained. It is also a little harder to demonstrate, and probably requires additional assumptions about the system, like the toy models have (Friedmann's equation, presence/non-presence of some terms...). My point is that if we assume only the basic GR (which has general covariance), then we can still observe why energy conservation isn't a universal law but a special condition valid in some frames.

Comment: I think it may be helpful to point out, that stating "energy conservation is obeyed", or "energy conservation is violated" implicitly assumed there is some special frame which is being talked about, or that it is supposed to be a general statement, independent of the frame. Well, in GR, based on the examples, it seems the second meaning is not possible. So we have to always ask "in which frame"?

Comment: Hm. On the other hand, there is a conserved ADM mass (which we can think of as a global energy of the spacetime) in asymptotically flat spacetimes, that is coordinate invariant. I would expect an argument about energy nonconservation in GR, to fail for asymptotically flat spacetimes, or at least address this point.

Comment: @Andrew maybe my argument fails, but I don't see how. ADM is based on some Hamiltonian, and there are known examples (already in classical mechanics) where Hamiltonian is not energy. So ADM may be conserved, it may even be zero, but connection to changes in kinetic energy of gravitating bodies seems unclear.

Comment: If there was some total energy-momentum tensor (densities and currents) that obeyed local conservation law and integral of its 00 component over the whole space was conserved, then I think my argument would have to be incorrect. But I guess that is not the case.

Comment: it's worth noting here that asymptotic flatness does give a notion of energy and momentum, through the Hamiltonian and momentum constraint, which is not derived from a toy model, but is an exact result on a broad class of spacetimes, well-approximated by a system like "the solar system asymptoting out to the space surrounding it"

Comment: @JánLalinský the adm mass is the hamiltonian, and you can get the kinetic terms of any fields in the spacetime by taking variations of it.  What is unclear?  The big restriction is that these things are only defined for asymptotically flat spacetime.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer It's unclear to me how any Hamiltonian provides any help to the question of how total energy is distributed in space. Can you derive from the ADM Hamiltonian an energy-momentum tensor $T$ that obeys $\nabla_{cov} \cdot T = 0$ and contains contribution due to gravity as well? Ordinary energy-momentum tensor (that one in Einstein's equations) does not reflect "gravity energy", only energy due to matter and EM field.